# angled bracket to attach a beam to a post?

Tags: wood, deck, decking

I am in the planning stages to build a deck around an oval pool. I have angles like the picture shows below (probably 30 degrees).. Is there a bracket i can use instead of the connection shown? NY building inspector doesn't like this and wants something with a bracket connection but has no suggestions
thanks for your help
Joe

[image]

Comment: That looks like the ideal to me. It's well supported and rigidly fastened. I'd ask your inspector what problem they're trying to solve with a bracket. He or she sounds like a briefcase carpenter.

Comment: I can't imagine a bracket doing a better job supporting this framing. you're looking at fourth generation carpentry here.

Comment: Ask the inspector how they'd feel about a run of Simpson strap. (Google Simpson CS - coiled strap)